# Text/Html panel is not displaying embedded iframe in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana 7.5.2.
I created new panel with Text visualation as HTML.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src=“http://www.google.com” width = 670 height = 510 ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It should display google page in panel. But not showing. I chabged below configurations but still not displaying page. It gives page not found 404 Error.

I changed `/usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini`, also changed `grafana.ini` and restarted grafana server but still it show below panel.

```
enable_alpha = true
disable_sanitize_html = true
enable_alpha = true
allow_embedding = true
cookie_samesite = none
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need only (please use correct quotes):

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width=670 height=510></iframe>
```

But you may have still many problems, e.g.:

- if Grafana is loaded via https, then http iframe will be very likely blocked, e.g. `Blocked loading mixed active content`
- iframed page also may have configuration to deny embeding, e.g. Google has usually header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, which will block

It is good idea to check browser console, where you can have more details about blocked iframe loading.

See https://github.com/jangaraj/grafana-iframe

Comment: Hello Jan, i corrected quotes. Now i get different error. It says www.google.com denied connection. I also tried other web pages but still same.

Comment: I have no https in both local and remote servers

Comment: As you said. From console. Refused to display 'http://www.....com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. How can i fix this ?

Comment: @ivbtar easy, be Google CEO and ask your employees to remove `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, so anyone on the Earth can include Google page into own iframe. Seriously, you expectation to use iframe for any page is wrong. Iframe are used for bad hacking attempts, so security aware page owner block option to include their page into iframe - that exactly the Google case.